# Wordpress site cannot open without www prefix in chrome

Tags: .htaccess

I tried googling this problem about a site do not open without www in chrome, But it works on other browser, here's my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mistake in your `.htaccess` file. You activate rewrite engine twice. Your `.htaccess` file has to be like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

## Update:

You can't open your site in chrome without `www.` because your `.htaccess` file contains redirection rule, what redirects your visitors from `mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain.com`. This rule is used for SEO, read through [Redirection SEO Best Practices](http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/redirection) article (especially Redirecting Canonical Hostnames paragraph) to become more familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I do your .htaccess, but still, it does not open in google chrome without www